# piping output of process to sh while loop?

Tags: while-loop, sh

I'm trying to loop over the output of a Perl process, line by line, within a `while` loop.  However, I'm having difficulty with the syntax.

I tried this, but got an "ambiguous redirect" error:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line; do 
    echo "$line" 
    # do stuff with $line 
done < $(perl process.pl)

./script.sh : line 6: $(perl process.pl): ambiguous redirect
```

For instance, one (inefficient) solution would be:

```
#!/bin/sh

tmpFile=/tmp/tmpFile.txt
perl process.pl > $tmpFile 
while read line; do 
    echo "$line" 
    # do stuff with $line 
done < $tmpFile
```

I know I can pipe the Perl process to a `while` loop as:

```
perl process.pl | while ...
```

but the while loop is executed in a subshell, and I need some variables set in the `while` loop to remain after the loop finished, so this is not an option.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Try this:

```
while read -r line; do 
    echo "$line" 
    # do stuff with $line 
done < <(perl process.pl)
```

The only difference is the `<` instead of the `$`.

`$(cmd)` is a command substitution, which expands to the output of the command within the parentheses. On the other hand, `<(cmd)` is a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution). Note that this is a Bash extension, so you should also change your shebang to be `#!/bin/bash` if you want to use this method.

Alternatively, if you are not using Bash, you can simply use a pipe instead:

```
perl process.pl | while read -r line; do 
    echo "$line" 
    # do stuff with $line 
done
```

As an aside, [you almost always want to use the `-r` switch with read](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read#read_without_-r)

Comment: OP's shebang is `#!/bin/sh`... but OP mentioned Bash and tagged question Bash... confusing (especially process substitutions are for Bash and not POSIX shells).

Comment: actually, the "pipe" solution was the first thing I came up with.  However, this executes the process in a subshell, and I lose any variables modified in in `# do stuff with $line`

Comment: @asf107 I'm not sure what you mean by "I lose everything that happens". You can redirect the output of the loop if you want?

Comment: If you are using a new enough version of `bash` (4.2 or later), you can execute `shopt -s lastpipe`, and the while loop in the piped version will execute in the current shell, not a subshell, preserving any variable changes made in the body of the loop.

Comment: @TomFenech Suppose the body of the while loop has a line like `linecount=$((linecount + 1))`. Any changes to this variable will be lost if the while loop is executed in a subshell.

Comment: @chepner ah yes I see. I guess if the OP is working in Bash there's no reason not to use process substitution anyway though.

Answer (score 2):

Use a named pipe; `bash` process substitution is essentially syntactic sugar around this.

```
mkfifo output
perl process.pl > output &
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    echo "$line" 
    # do stuff with $line 
done < output
rm output
```

The named pipe does not require `process.pl` to complete before the `while` loop begins consuming the output.

Comment: interesting, i didn't even know such a thing existed :)  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a [here-document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07_04):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line" 
    # do stuff with $line 
done <<EOF
$(perl process.pl)
EOF
```