# Emulate reading from file on application argument

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, command-line-interface, sh

I'm working with a command line application (`geth`) that accepts the argument `--password` **which expects a valid path of a file containing a password**, i.e.:

```
geth --password /some/path/to/password/file
```

I'm trying to **specify the password on the command line** (I'm aware of the security implications) instead of keeping it on a file, for example:

```
geth --password `echo P@ssWordHer3`
```

The above doesn't work because `geth` is searching for a file named `P@ssWordHer3`, which doesn't exist:

> Fatal: Failed to read password file: open P@ssWordHer3: no such file
>   or directory

I was thinking about creating a shell script that would accept a password as argument and output it, but I guess it also doesn't work because `geth`  will try read the **file content** instead of the **output**.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the ksh and bash feature known as [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) is for:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- also works on ksh, but not on baseline-POSIX /bin/sh

geth --password <(echo 'P@sswordHer3')
```

The `<(...)` expansion will be replaced with a filename which, when read from, will return the output of the code contained therein.

Note that this is a FIFO (either a named pipe or a `/dev/fd/...`-style name, depending on the operating system), so it can only be read once, front-to-back, and does not allow seeking or rereading.

---

If you need a real file, as opposed to a FIFO, zsh (which I personally don't recommend) has an expansion for that too:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
geth --password =(echo 'P@sswordHer3')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm getting an error: `sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token \`('` .

Comment: As the answer says, it's a ksh and bash feature. `sh` doesn't support it. (See also the comment in the first code sample: *"also works on ksh, but not on baseline-POSIX /bin/sh"*)

Comment: Yes, I got it, I'm using `CentOS7-x64`, any idea how to emulate this behavior on `/bin/sh` ?

Comment: Painfully. You *can* run `mkfifo` yourself, start a background process feeding your password into the FIFO, and tear it all down, but it's not fun at all. Is there a reason you want to use `/bin/sh`?

Comment: (Also, why did you add a `bash` tag to your question if you aren't willing to accept an answer written in bash?)

Comment: **Is there a reason you want to use /bin/sh** - what else can I use on CentOS 7 that could solve my problem?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, as the code in the answer uses. Or if you're running your script with `sh scriptname`, use `bash scriptname` instead.

Comment: The following code worked if placed inside a bash file and executed : `#!/usr/bin/env bash
geth --password <(echo -n 'P@sswordHer3') account new`. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Consider `printf '%s' 'P@sswordHer3'` instead of `echo -n 'P@sswordHer3'` -- the `-n` argument to `echo` is only very loosely POSIX-standardized (POSIX says that `echo` is allowed to behave in an unspecified manner when it's present).

Comment: BTW, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26913000/14122 for an example of emulating process substitution with /bin/sh -- though it's not a particularly good example (vulnerable to symlink attacks, for example).